# Need to dynamically build checkboxes in angular from JSON object loaded from ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON doc in the following format and need to use that to dynamically build check boxes using angular.

```
var data = {
"Name":[
    {
        "tagId":4489,"name":"Name","label":"Employee Name"
    }
],
"Service":[
    {
        "tagId":1722,"name":"good service","label":"Good Service"
    },
    {
        "tagId":3707,"name":"bad service","label":"Bad Service"
    }
]};
```

I am just learning Angular js and the project I am working on will need the check boxes in the following format.

## Name

[ ] Employee Name

## Service

[ ] Good Service

[ ] Bad Service

The JSON is loaded on startup with ajax in my main controller. I am not quite sure how let Angular build this for me using the ng-repeat function.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my fiddle. I belive my answer is a bit more complete than Khalil's.

http://jsfiddle.net/nicolasmoise/8YQPh/1

I have created a factory `.factory('checkBoxFactory', function(){})` which takes the JSON object and adds a check="false" to every tag. This may not be necessary, but I believe it's better to set the values right away in case the user doesn't touch them.

Finally, I have directive `.directive('checkboxes', function(){})` which takes the checkboxes I have created through the factory and creates the desired markup. With this you can change the name of your categories (Name, Service) and it still works.

Let me know if this is not what you had in mind or if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

I made a jsfiddle of the most basic example of what you're looking for [over here.](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1680/)

Basically I just attached `data` to the scope and iterated over both lists, `"Service"` and `"Name"` and used `input`s with `type=checkbox`([angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput.checkbox)) and attached an `ng-model` linked to a `check` value on each object (this will be added by angular when you activate the checkbox).

You can monitor the values of the checkboxes by referencing `check` on each object. I do this by doing `ng-repeat="service in data.Service"` and then calling `service.check`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.  The only thing is that I don't want to refer to data.Name or data.Service directly because those are dynamic values and might be something else. Does this make sense?  I also wont know how many of those top level elements there are.

Comment: You can solve that by nesting `ng-repeat`s. You just use a `div` or `span` to iterate through the top level elements and then just throw the lower level `ng-repeat` beneath that.

Here, I updated my example to show this.
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/1686/